# Handling callback from Google OAuth using ASP.NET Core Web API and SPA

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, oauth, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to setup Google login for my project but I seem to struggle understanding the proper flow once the request comes back from Google's `signin-google` middleware and then back to my own callback defined in my Web API, also, handling everything in the UI side (React in this case).

I debugged my callback endpoint and I do get the code etc from the signin-google initial callback. I'm stuck as I don't really know where to go next, I do know that I would need to have checks to see if that user already exists, otherwise create an account for them in my database.

But from here on wards, what would the process be to make sure I can login and display the info on my client side.

In my project I'm using JWT tokens for auth and already have the functionality or normal signup/signin but nothing with an external provider.

Any help will be appreciated.

**What I have at the moment**

- Set up my project, credentials, consent screens in Google cloud
- Configured the Google credentials in my `AddAuthentication().AddGoogle()` of my `program.cs`:

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
.AddCookie(options => {
    options.LoginPath = "/auth/unauthorized";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/auth/forbidden";
}).AddJwtBearer(opts => {
    opts.SaveToken = true;
    opts.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
}).AddGoogle(options => {
    IConfigurationSection googleAuthSection = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");
    options.ClientId = googleAuthSection["ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = googleAuthSection["ClientSecret"];
});
```

I have an endpoint which I call when a user clicks "Sign in with google" which takes me to Googles login page:

```cs
[HttpGet("google")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleLogin(string? returnUrl) 
{
    const string provider = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    var properties = new AuthenticationProperties {
                RedirectUri = Url.Action("GoogleCallback", "Auth", new { returnUrl})
            };
    return Challenge(properties, provider);
}
```

and the ReactJS button

```js
const handleGoogleAuthentication = () => {
    var clientId = "myclientid";
    var redirectUri = "https://localhost:7132/api/auth/google";
    var scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";
    var googleCallbackUrl = `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&scope=${encodeURIComponent(scope)}&access_type=online&prompt=select_account&state=${""}`;
    window.location.href = googleCallbackUrl;
}
```

I also have an endpoint for the Google callback (not much here), here is where I'm lost since most tutorials I've seen cover ASP.NET Core MVC, Razor pages etc.

```cs
[HttpGet("googlecallback", Name = "GoogleCallback")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleCallback() 
{
    string code = HttpContext.Request.Query["code"];
    string scope = HttpContext.Request.Query["scope"];
    string authUser = HttpContext.Request.Query["authUser"];
    string prompt = HttpContext.Request.Query["prompt"];
}
```

Comment: You have a two port application.  The frontend is a http connection from client to server.  The backend is a connection from server to database.  The OAUTH is only on the frontend and not the credentials on the backend database.  The best way of solving this is to create a group account in the database for access.  The when a user fails to have access to the database you add the user on the client to the Group. Nothing need to be changed on the backend.  Then user becomes a member of the Role like other users of the database.

Comment: Normally, we have the frontend to get the access token and use that access token to access the API. So you could try this way, directly get token inside the frontend and use that token to access google protected API.

Comment: @Brando Zhang I did it this way, in my frontend I just send the user to the google login page with my client id and scope etc. After they choose their account and it comes to the server in my custom callback, i retrieve the code from the URL and then use that to make a POST request to get back an access token ( This is wwhat i use to make a GET request to get the users external info).

After that my code just checks if the user exists with that email and either creates an account and then generates a JWT token, or just generates a token if they already exist.

Does this approach seem fine?

Comment: At the moment, Im just trying to find out how I can send the user back to my UI after the google login screen